# NDK error-cannot do ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using NDK for my project...
My android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libfreeimage
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=libfreeimage.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= imageprocessing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= imageprocessing.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES:= libfreeimage
LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -lm -llog -ljnigraphicss
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The error that I get-

```
flock@QS57:~/Desktop/android-imagefilter-ndk$ /home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/build/core/imageprocessing.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/imageprocessing/imageprocessing.o'.  Stop.
```

And my file hierarchy...

```
jni-
  Android.mk 
  imageprocessing.cpp  
  libfreeimage.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
I got the solution and it was because I gave " LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) " twice.I deleted the second " LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) " and the problem was solved.